# Is there any way to show <img> alt text attributes in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, images

Outlook seems to be pretty tight with images, blocking them altogether if they use an external src:

> Microsoft Outlook is configured by default to block automatic picture downloads from the Internet.
>
> <sup>- [Block or unblock automatic picture downloads in email messages, Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/block-or-unblock-automatic-picture-downloads-in-email-messages-15e08854-6808-49b1-9a0a-50b81f2d617a)</sup>

But what about  alt attributes, like `<img src="https://something.com/logo.png" alt="This image contains my logo">`? Outlook seems to ignore them too even though it's not mentioned in that article.

Is there any way to at least show the alt text if the images are automatically blocked? Without it if your recipients use Outlook, they just see a bunch of weird white rectangles with error signs on them.

[image: Outlook blocks images without showing their alt text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try setting width and height of the image in the image tag as this thread mentioned:[ALT text not showing up in email (Outlook)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916504).

If it still could not work, I'm afraid that Outlook indeed will not show alt text, just as the similar thread says. [HTML ALT text is not showing in Outllok](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other-mso_2010/html-alt-text-is-not-showing-in-outllok/b539010d-5a48-484f-8842-29db54d4e473).

Comment: Width doesn't help, see updated screenshot.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, seems we could indeed not able to make it happen in Outlook.